# Blazor Role Based Authorization Return False

Tags: authorization, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have the blazor with roled based.

I loop the claims from context.user. It has following claims:

```
  Hello superadmin@gmail.com !!
Type: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name + Value: superadmin@gmail.com
Type: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier32678458 + Value: afa68479-28eb-4823-889c-70e4b161aecf
Type: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name15158991 + Value: superadmin@gmail.com
Type: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress49903371 + Value: superadmin@gmail.com
Type: AspNet.Identity.SecurityStamp41337846 + Value: YLXYUYXMPICHEHR3J3SFWGPV366GEOTP
Type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role62788414 + Value: Basic
Type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role43488279 + Value: SuperAdmin
```

In the component view I have authorise component like below

```
<AuthorizeView Roles="SuperAdmin">
    <p>You can only see this if you're an admin.</p>
</AuthorizeView>
<AuthorizeView Roles="Basic">
    <p>You can only see this if you're an basic.</p>
</AuthorizeView>
```

When I run the project it showed nothing - I logged with SuperAdmin user which of cousrse has SuperAdmin role. And I check the console. It showed as below.

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
  Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
  RolesAuthorizationRequirement:User.IsInRole must be true for one of the following roles: (SuperAdmin)
```

What wrong with this?

Comment: Have a look here if your just using the standard Identity template project from VS. https://github.com/BrianLParker/AuthApp

Comment: Did you manage to fix it?